# Why do these static routes need to be bi-directional?

Tags: routing, asymmetric-routing

I am setting up a testbed for some VMs. These routes need to be static as this is an academic project. (I know that doing this manually is generally a bad idea. Trust me, I have a reason for this.)

I'm running into an issue where my hosts on the far ends cannot ping each other unless the route to and from go through all of the same hosts. Can someone help and explain why this is? Is there any way that I can set it up so that the return route is separate? For example, in the image below, can I make the ping out from n0 go through n1 -> n2 -> n4 -> n5 and return on n5 -> n4 -> n3 -> n1 -> n0?

Here is my network. Everything is a 10.1.y.x address. The links are shown with the last two octets.

```
              n2
            /     \
           / 2.x   \6.x
   5.x    /         \     4.x
n0 ---- n1           n4 ----- n5
          \         /
           \ 3.x   /1.x
            \     /
              n3
```

Here are the routing tables for each, if that makes it clearer. All taken from "ip route":

n0

```
10.1.4.0/24 via 10.1.5.3 dev eth2 
10.1.5.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.5.2 
10.1.6.0/24 via 10.1.5.3 dev eth2 
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.5.3 dev eth2 
10.1.2.0/24 via 10.1.5.3 dev eth2 
10.1.3.0/24 via 10.1.5.3 dev eth2
```

n1

```
10.1.4.0/24 via 10.1.3.3 dev eth3 
10.1.5.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.5.3 
10.1.6.0/24 via 10.1.2.3 dev eth4 
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.3.3 dev eth3 
10.1.2.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.2.2 
10.1.3.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.3.2
```

n2

```
10.1.4.0/24 via 10.1.6.3 dev eth2 
10.1.5.0/24 via 10.1.2.2 dev eth4 
10.1.6.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.6.2 
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.6.3 dev eth2 
10.1.2.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.2.3 
10.1.3.0/24 via 10.1.2.2 dev eth4
```

n3

```
10.1.4.0/24 via 10.1.1.3 dev eth4 
10.1.5.0/24 via 10.1.3.2 dev eth3 
10.1.6.0/24 via 10.1.1.3 dev eth4 
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.2 
10.1.2.0/24 via 10.1.3.2 dev eth3 
10.1.3.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.3.3
```

n4

```
10.1.4.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.4.2 
10.1.5.0/24 via 10.1.6.2 dev eth2 
10.1.6.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.6.3 
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.3 
10.1.2.0/24 via 10.1.6.2 dev eth2 
10.1.3.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 dev eth4
```

n5

```
10.1.4.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.4.3 
10.1.5.0/24 via 10.1.4.2 dev eth2 
10.1.6.0/24 via 10.1.4.2 dev eth2 
10.1.2.0/24 via 10.1.4.2 dev eth2 
10.1.3.0/24 via 10.1.4.2 dev eth2
```

Comment: Are there any firewall features running on any of these?

Comment: to precise the reason for @YLearn insightful question : if you have a firewall along the way : if it only sees an "ack" in reply to a "syn" it didn't see pass through, it will likely drop the ack paquet, as it is for an unknown (to that fw) communication, one it didn't see open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove reverse path filtering on your linux routers (n1 to n4).
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031

Comment: This does the trick on the default Ubuntu machines I'm using. In case the link dies, here's the command to take them down:

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=2

Answer (score 4):

> can I make the ping out from n0 go through n1 -> n2 -> n4 -> n5 and return on n5 -> n4 -> n3 -> n1 -> n0?

Yes, you can.

As per the information in your post, n0's IP address is 10.1.5.2. Therefore to alter the return path you will need to change the route for 10.1.5.0 on n4.

Currently it looks like this:

```
10.1.5.0/24 via 10.1.6.2 dev eth2
```

What you will need to do is change it to this:

```
10.1.5.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 dev eth4
```

The reason being that your current route (10.1.5.0/24 via 10.1.6.2 dev eth2) points to n2, whereas "10.1.1.2 dev eth4" points to n3 as per your diagram.

Therefore my suggested change above says "traffic which hits n4 and has a destination IP address of 10.1.5.0/24 can reach its destination by going through eth4."

In other words, this will result in traffic flowing in the following manner: n5 - n4 - n3 - n1 - n0. In other words, traffic from n5 to n0 will go via n3.

In order for traffic in the opposite direction to take the other route (n0 - n1 - n2 - n4 - n5, in other words, traffic from n0 to n5 will go via n2) you will need to do the following:

Remove this from n1:

```
10.1.4.0/24 via 10.1.3.3 dev eth3
```

And add this on n1:

```
10.1.4.0/24 via 10.1.2.3 dev eth4
```

Comment: Right. That will put everything going through n0 - n1 - n3 - n4 - n5. So, if on n1 I add 10.1.4.0/24 via 10.1.2.2 (n2), that should work, right? Outbound traffic from n0 would go through the top path and return through the bottom? Whenever I tried that (asymmetric routing) I never got the pings back. I will give it another go.

Comment: I edited my answer to include more details. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: @Maxthecat have you had a chance to see if the above solution resolved your issue?

Comment: Thanks, your answer was incredibly insightful. The solution does work, but my primary error was in not removing the reverse path filtering in Linux, which Xavier suggested. Since I can only pick one answer, I went with that, but yours certainly gets an upvote for the insight.

Comment: No worries at all :) I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

For having bidirectional static route Configuration for    N1->N2->N3 ,and from  N3->N2-N1 is for both forward and reverse traffic from client -> server & server --> client

To ensure communication between Client and server before actually session start ,TCP handshake should be successful complete then only actually session establish between client and servers for exchanging data . For TCP handshake and for actuall data transfer both client--->server & server-client network path souce be through . Because of this reason bidirectional static routes are required .